# USB KVM corrupting page files?

Tags: usb, hardware-failure, bsod, kvm-switch

I have three computers hooked up to a [4-way USB KVM switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L6VSFC8) - two Windows laptops and a Mac tower.  One of the laptops has periodically experienced a bluescreen with a `FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE` error, and based on the event log, this occurs "by memory corruption due to physical memory access" ([Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x12b---faulty-hardware-corrupted-page)).

The Mac tower has occasionally kernel panicked, although I've never traced down a cause - I just assumed that it was old enough that the components were occasionally failing.

Today, the second laptop rebooted itself and had the same `FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE` and "bugcheck 0x0000012b" error.

Since the only attached device that they all share is the KVM switch, I'm now suspecting that it is the source of this memory corruption.  I would be surprised if a peripheral had access to modify the physical RAM pages, but I can't think of anything else shared across all three computers.  **Is this switch actually a viable possible source of all these crashes?**  I don't want to replace it needlessly (it's worked quite well for me), but if it's likely to be my problem, I can look for an alternative.

Comment: "*Is this switch actually a viable possible source of all these crashes?*" -- No.

Comment: @sawdust That's what I would have expected - if you were able to do something like that via a USB port, that implies a disturbingly large attack surface.  I just couldn't come up with anything better that could possibly explain why two (or three) totally different computers would have the same symptoms.  Hence wanting to get a sanity check.